# scons is ignoring file destination path?

Tags: python, scons

I'm seeing some weird behaviour from scons 2.3.0.  Perhaps I'm just Doing It Wrong™, but this seems like it ought to be sensible...

```
destinations = [base_dir+'lib/', base_dir+'tree/usr/local/lib/']
boost_ver = '1.63.0'
boost_libs = (x for x in env['LIBS'] if 'boost_' in x)
# eg. 'boost_thread', 'boost_system'

for dest in destinations:
    for lib_name in boost_libs:
        lib_so = 'lib'+lib_name+'.so'
        lib_so_ver = lib_so+'.'+boost_ver

        env.Command(dest+lib_so_ver, libsrc+lib_so_ver, Copy("$TARGET","$SOURCE"))
        env.Command(dest+lib_so, dest+lib_so_ver, SymLink)
```

The point being to take the named libraries and copy them from `libsrc` to each of the `destinations`, recreating the non-versioned symlink as it goes.  (`base_dir` and `libsrc` are absolute paths, though `base_dir` points inside the scons output tree.)

This works fine for a single destination, but the copying or linking never occurs for any other destinations.  I've tried adding explicit dependencies with `env.Depends`; I've tried assigning the result to variables and using that later; nothing seems to work.

If I look at the output of `--tree`, invariably only the files in the first destination are listed; any subsequent ones never are.  (If I change the order they're listed in, then whatever is now first is the only one listed.)

If I add an alias target for each destination, and make it `Depends` on the result of the commands, then both alias targets appear in the tree but only the first one has sub-items; whichever appears second always has no children.

Even if I explicitly specify the second alias target on the command line, it does nothing and prints no children in the `--tree`.  Only by re-ordering the destinations can I get it to do anything -- and then of course the other one stops working.

Basically, it appears to be acting like only one action is possible for any given input file, and just completely ignoring any attempts to use a source file multiple times, without even so much as a warning.  Which just seems nuts.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about what the `SymLink` method(?) is doing and why it doesn't seem to need any arguments? I can't find a method/factory with this name in the UserGuide/sources...neither for SCons 2.3.0, nor for the latest 2.5.1.

Comment: It's just a locally-defined python function (`def SymLink(target, source, env)`) that does what it sounds like.  It's using the standard scons [custom action extension mechanism](http://scons.org/doc/2.3.0/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-commands) and is not relevant to this issue.

Comment: To clarify: both the copy and the symlink work for a single destination.  Neither the copy nor the symlink work for any additional destinations, because scons appears to be ignoring the additional `Command`.  The only theory I have as to why this happens is that the source is the same for the first command in each pair between all destinations.  But this seems like a dumb reason for it to fail, if that is indeed the reason.

Comment: I converted your code snippet to a minimal example SConstruct, which works as expected under SCons v2.3.3 on my side. Check #2 of our [most frequently asked FAQs](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), and if the problem persists bring it to our Users Mailing List [scons-users@scons.org](http://scons.org/lists.html), please.

Comment: According to the answer, the problem isn't with given code, but with **modified code**. So what is a reason in the question?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm not sure what you're asking.  Yes, it turns out that the question was asking the wrong thing, which the answer addresses.  But it seems like a natural confusion for someone using scons who does not know enough Python to recognise what the real problem was, so this question and answer still seems potentially useful to others from that perspective, so I don't want to delete it, and editing it after the fact to be more "correct" doesn't seem worthwhile to me (and would make the existing comments more confusing).

Comment: `who does not know enough Python to recognise what the real problem was` - Exactly for such people it is suggested to provide **exact code** which causes the problem. BTW, my knowledges in Python are very limited too, but the behavior of the SCons described in the question confuses me a lot. Please, do edit the code in the question (even after the answering). The reason `would make the existing comments more confusing` doesn't prevent editing the question: it is *real purpose* of the comments to make the question post better.

Comment: Fine.  Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't an issue with Scons, but with Python.  The Real Problem™ is this definition:

```
boost_libs = (x for x in env['LIBS'] if 'boost_' in x)
```

For whatever reason (clearly my python-fu is not high enough) this results in the inner for loop above executing only once for the first destination.

The solution is to use square brackets instead:

```
boost_libs = [x for x in env['LIBS'] if 'boost_' in x]
```

This correctly executes the inner loop for every destination.

Comment: For reference, I now know the reason -- the syntax with parentheses is a generator, which can only be iterated once.  Conversely with square brackets it's a list, which can be iterated many times.  Just to be extra confusing, tuples (which also use parentheses) can also be iterated many times.

Comment: (The confusing thing about tuples was that the code had previously read `('boost_thread', 'boost_system')`, and this worked as expected -- but giving it an expression while keeping the parentheses broke it.  So this was my fault for not knowing about generators, apparently, but the prior developer contributed to the confusion by using a tuple instead of a list.)